# @Html.Textbox validation and onclick=confirm don't work together

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor, model-view-controller

I have a code like below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateEmail", "Default"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("emailAddress", "", new
    {
        @type = "email", 
        @required = "true", 
        @pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}"})        
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to proceed?')" />
}
```

The problem is, that email validation message and "onclick='return confirm()'" both don't work together. It's either one or the other. What should I do?

Comment: Why are you not using mvc built in client side validation (which does all this out of the box) - i.e. by adding validation attributes and using the `jquery,validate.js and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` plugins. And your code only gives HTML-5 validation in the browser and anyone can bypass that so you just have to repeat the validation all over again in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a similar thing in my project but I simply enable / disable the submit button accordingly in JQuery.

```
$("#txtEmail").on("blur", function () {
        var email = $(this).val().toString();
        var pattern = "YOUR_PATTERN";

        if (email.match(pattern)) {
            alert("valid");
            //Enable Submit button
        } else {
            alert("invalid");
            //Disable submit button
        }
    });
```

You could of course intercept the Submit of the form also, then validate the contents there. Change the type of your button to "button" and capture the click event. Also assign a name to your form. Enables easier selection for posting.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateEmail", "Default", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmMyEmailForm" }))
 {
 }

 $("#btnSubmitForm").on('click', function () {

        var email = $("#txtEmail").val().toString();
        var pattern = "YOUR_PATTERN";

        if (email.match(pattern)) {
            $("#frmMyEmailForm").submit();
        } else {
            alert("invalid");
            //Disable submit button
        }
    });
```

Something similar to the above should achieve what you need.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call unobtrusive validation manually in jquery onclick

```
function submitForm(action) {
var $form = $("#myForm");
$form.action = "/Area/MyController/" + action;

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
$form.validate();

if ($form.valid()) {
  return confirm('Are you sure you wish to proceed?');
}
}
```